# How do I write conditional statement with two parts that if met THEN

Tags: python, excel, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am fairly new to Python and have tried a few different things but I keep getting small syntax errors or just nothing being printed back.

I have a Excel sheet that has 4 columns with 40 rows.
Snippet of my Excel sheet.

```
Name  Age Pet(s) Married
john  30   1      yes
mary  25   2      no
.
.
.
```

I want to create a conditional statement that says

```
if ((df['age'] > 20) & (df['pet'] > 2)) 
    print that line.
```

I want to repeat the process until the code has reached the end of the data set. Above is my attempt at trying to create the conditional, however it is not printing anything. I am not having any issues opening and reading the excel file just the conditional statement.

```
FilePath = "location of file"
FileName = "Name of file"

df = pd.read_excel(FilePath + '//' + FileName + '.xlsx'

.
.
.

For i in range( 0, len(df['age'])
    if ((df['age'] > 20) & (df['pet'] > 2)) 
      print line
```

Comment: "I am fairly new to Python and have tried a few different things but I keep getting small syntax errors or just nothing being printed back." Then Stack Overflow is not the right place to resolve the issue; we expect **one** question at a time, which is **explicitly asked, specific and clear**. There are many things wrong in the example code, many of which would be considered typos by experienced developers. It would be better to follow a Python tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals, before trying to work with third-party libraries like Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'age'] > 20) and (df.loc[i, 'pet'] > 2):
        print(df.loc[i])
```

You want to specify a certain row in `age` and `pet` columns using the `.loc`  method. Also, use `range(len(df))` to iterate through the number of rows in the entire dataframe instead of `len(df['age'])`.